# jQuery href left click not working

Tags: jquery, html

Got this code which I have adapted slightly from a book (novice to ninja).

The user clicks on 'contact' and a form opens underneath with a phone number and href  link. Left clicking on the  link does nothing, but i can right click and 'open in a new tab' and then it does work.

Fairly new to js and jQuery, but I think the problem (and i maybe wrong) is that the href link that doesnt work properly is linked the same 'a' as the 'Contact' link that opens the form, but I dont know how to change that.

```
      <div id="contact">
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <form action="">
    Phone me on:018<br><br>Email me at <a href="http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/2012/apr/04/samantha-brick-hated-good-looks?newsfeed=true">click me</a>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
  $('#contact form').hide();
  $('#contact a').toggle(function() {
  $(this)
  .addClass('active')
  .next('form')
  .animate({'height':'show'}, {
    duration:'slow',
    easing: 'swing'
  });
  }, function() {
  $(this)
  .removeClass('active')
  .next('form')
  .slideUp();
  });
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
$('#contact a')
```

try using

```
$('#contact > a')
```

in this way you target only the direct child and not the other `<a>`. I think that your snippets runs also when you click on the link with the href `<a href="http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/2012/apr/04/samantha-brick-hated-good-looks?newsfeed=true">click me</a>`, and the script breaks and the link is not followed for that reason